# Get project fields from query using optional values [mongoDb]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following query which gets the data that has `date.start_time` greater than `new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365`

Here is the query:

```
query = EoCHistory.find({
    $and: [
        { $or: ors },
        { 'date.start_time': { $gt: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 } },
    ],
});
```

I want to also include all those entries that DO NOT have `date.start_time`

How can this be achieved?

What I tried is:

```
query = EoCHistory.find({
    $and: [
        { $or: ors },
        {
            'date.start_time': {
                $or: [{ $gt: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 }, undefined],
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

And

```
query = EoCHistory.find({
    $and: [
        { $or: ors },
        {
            'date.start_time': {
                $or: [{ $gt: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 }, { $exists: false }],
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea by just wrapping it with an additional `$or` you just have a minor syntax error, try this:

```
query = EoCHistory.find({
    $and: [
        { $or: ors },
        {
            $or: [
                {
                    'date.start_time': { $gt: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 },
                },
                {
                    'date.start_time': { $exists: false },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
});
```